# Combine PHP Webservice and C# Client

Tags: c#, php, web-services, callback

I have a C#/Winforms application using PHP webservices. A first PHP webservice uploadFile.php is used to upload a blob file (by a unix application for example) on a mysql database and another webservice, getFile.php (code below), is used to get the file if a file is available for the client.

For the moment the client calls every 5 seconds the webservice. Obviously Apache cannot deal with all the connections and gets slow and is often down or timeout, Today I have counted 2000 connections in 2 minutes, and 100 000 in 25 minutes. 99% of them return no file.

So instead of calling every 5 (or 10 or 20 or else) seconds the webservice, I would like the webservice uploadFile to notify the client when a result is available. I'm not familiar with SOAP/REST or any other kind of webservices, and for practical reasons (old versions of the application still running) I could not replace the current webservice with REST. Here is what currently does the webservice getOK.php :

```
 if(getJobsForUser($login, $serveur)){

    //data is BLOB content
    $query = "SELECT idjob,fileName,data FROM JobSpool WHERE idcompte=$idcompte LIMIT 1" ;  
    $stmt = $pdo->query($query);
    $res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);  
    $idjob = $res[0] ;
    $nomfic = $res[1] ;
    $data = $res[2] ;
    //send datas to client
    echo $nomfic."\n" ;
    echo $data ; 
 }

 function checkJobsforUser($login, $serveur){
    global $pdo, $idcompte;

    $query = "SELECT count(*),c.idcompte FROM Compte as c,Job as j WHERE c.login='$login' AND c.serveur = '$serveur' AND j.idcompte = c.idcompte" ;

    $stmt = $pdo->query($query);
    $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    //print_r($results);
    $count = $results[0];
    $idcompte = $results[1];
    //echo "count : $count, idcompte : $idcompte <br/>";
    if($count > 0)
        return true;
    return false;
```

}

C# code :

```
public String getMyFile(){
    String nomFicFinal = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest hwr;
        String request = "http://myWebServiceDomain.com/getFile.php?login=myLogin&otherId=myOtherId";
        hwr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(request);

        using (HttpWebResponse hwrep = (HttpWebResponse)hwr.GetResponse())
        {
            //read datas 
            br = new BinaryReader(hwrep.GetResponseStream());
            Byte[] tmp = new Byte[256];
            int b = br.Read();
            while (b != -1)
            {
                if (b == 10) break;
                tmp[indNomFic++] = (Byte)b;
                b = br.Read();
            }

            //get filename
            nomFicFinal = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tmp, 0, indNomFic);

            //if parsed data == "0" nothing returned
            if (nomFicFinal.Length == 1 && (nomFicFinal.CompareTo("0") == 0 || nomFicFinal.CompareTo("1") == 0))
            {
                br.Close();
                nomFicFinal = "";
            }
            else //we parse the content of the request and we create the file with the name nomFicFinal in ApplicationData
            {
                nomFicFinal = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\MyApp\" + nomFicFinal;
                bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(nomFicFinal, FileMode.Create));

                tmp = new Byte[1024];
                while ((tmp = br.ReadBytes(1024)) != null)
                {
                    if (tmp.Length == 0) break;
                    bw.Write(tmp);
                    bw.Flush();
                }
                br.Close();
                bw.Close();
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        //do something
    }

    return nomFicFinal;

}
```

I have been searching with "callback PHP C#", etc, but I still do not have a clear idea of what to do for the moment.

Comment: What's actually hitting what? The c# application is hitting the php app? What is "the client" in your question?

Comment: A Unix application hits the uploadFile.php. During this time the C# application periodically hits getFile.php. Hope it's more clear

Comment: So the unix application uploads the file, and the c# application get's the file? What not just upload the file directly to c#?

Comment: because we have many clients and different unix servers hosting the unix app, sometimes not in the same region. And the C# is a client app (one by user). 
But what did you mean but uploading directly to C# ?

Comment: I mean, if c# is the one that's making the requests, and he's polling the server every 5 seconds, it shouldn't cause that much of a load. If the requests finish in < 100ms, then the connection shouldn't stay open, and apache shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: As far as a notify option, you could simply just ping a url to tell c# that it has new results. For example, `php.example.com` gets an upload. Processes the file, and calls [`csharp.anotherexample.com/api/newUpload`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) (Can probably just push the file to it, or simply just say, 'New upload'). At that point, your c# app, checks for new files, or receives the file.

Comment: There are 300 apache threads permantly in use. We tried to change mysql_pconnect for mysql_connect and mysql_close but still the same. I only counted 125 distinct users for the moment

Comment: I didn't put all the code, sorry. I already check if there is a result before calling this. I'm goint to edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93605/discussion-between-user3651845-and-frankerz).

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time. Dont poll the webservice!

Call the PHP webservice from Winforms (sorry im still stuck in VB) with:

```
Public Function callServer(ByVal strURL As String, ByVal strCallString As String, Optional ByVal intWaitTimeIncrease As Integer = 0) As String

        'USE:  strResult = callServer(My.Settings.sf_GetData, SQL_Composite)

        callServer = ""

            If strCallString <> "" Then

                debugLog(strURL & " -> " & strCallString)

                strCallString = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strCallString) 'IF WE DONT ENCODE THIS HERE THEN ? & AND MAYBE OTHER CHARACTERS GET REMOVED

                Dim wRequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(strURL)) ' & "?SQL=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(SQL_Composite)))

                With wRequest

                    ' .AllowWriteStreamBuffering = False

                    .CookieContainer = ClientSettings.wsCookies
                    .Timeout = My.Settings.WebserviceTimeout + 5000 + My.Settings.WebserviceTimeoutUserAdjustment + intWaitTimeIncrease
                    .Proxy = ClientSettings.myWebProxy
                    .KeepAlive = False
                    .ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" '"text/plain"
                    .Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post

                    Dim bPostData As Byte() = Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SQL=" & strCallString)

                    .ContentLength = bPostData.Length

                    Using dataStream = .GetRequestStream()
                        dataStream.Write(bPostData, 0, bPostData.Length)
                    End Using

                    Using httpWebResponse = TryCast(.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

                        If httpWebResponse IsNot Nothing Then

                            Dim responseUri As String = httpWebResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri

                            .CookieContainer.Add(httpWebResponse.Cookies)

                            Using streamReader = New StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
                                callServer = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
                            End Using

                            If callServer.StartsWith(vbCrLf) Then callServer = replaceFirstFound(callServer, vbCrLf, "")
                            If callServer.StartsWith(vbLf) Then callServer = replaceFirstFound(callServer, vbLf, "")

                        End If
                    End Using

                End With
            End If

    End Function
```

The PHP

```
function exchangeData($compositeSQL) {
    //HERE YOU WRITE YOUR DATABASE CALLS AND RETURN INFORMATION
    //THEN YOU JUST 'return (string) x;' AS A PRODUCT OF THE FUNCTION
}

if (!empty($_POST["SQL"])) {
    echo (string) exchangeData($_POST["SQL"]);
}
```